# How To Define Nancy Path With Query Paremeters

Tags: c#, asp.net, nancy

I am trying to define a path with query parameters, but it doesn't seem to be mapping.

The path is pretty simple, here is an example

Get['api/entities?page=1&pageSize=10']

Although it keeps hitting the path that has no query string defined:

Get['api/entities']

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is not considered part of the route, but you could do this using a [conditional route](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#condition)

For instance like this:

```
public class MyModule : NancyModule
{
    public MyModule()
    {
        Get["api/entities", ctx => ctx.Query.ContainsKey("page") && ctx.Query.ContainsKey("pageSize")] = p => DoStuff();
        Get["api/entities", ctx => !(ctx.Query.ContainsKey("page") && ctx.Query.ContainsKey("pageSize"))] = p => DoOtherStuff();
    }
}
```

The second argument to the route is a predicate taking in a `NancyContext` object. The route only matches if the predicate is true.